# setRowspan in iText 1.3

Tags: java, itext

I am making a PDF with **iText 1.3** and I use to combine 2 lines, I have investigated that higher versions is the `setRowspan` method, but in the version I am occupying it is not found. ¿How can I achieve that function in iText 1.3?

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
cell.setColspan(2);
table.addCell(cell);
//First cell to combine
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Something text"));
cell.setBackgroundColor(colorVerdeOscuro);
table.addCell(cell);
table.addCell("112128");
table.addCell("Something text");
//Second cell to combine
table.addCell("");
document.add(pdfTable);
```

Comment: Please do consider updating. Itext 1.3 is **ancient**.

Comment: I can´t because use Java 1.4, is the version of the application

Comment: At least up to 2.1.7 should be compilable using java 1.4, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks with that version already works!